# import pycrypto in dev_appserver.py on Google App Engine gives IOError

Tags: google-app-engine, pycrypto

I am trying to test a Google App Engine app with `dev_appserver.py`, but when I run `import Crypto` I get the following excerpted from the `IOError` (i.e. No access) traceback:

```
...
import Crypto
...
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
      /2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 867, in read
    return self.open(name, "r", pwd).read()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
        /2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 882, in open
    zef_file = open(self.filename, 'rb')
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/
       GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google
       /appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 592, in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
                                    /pycrypto-2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg'
```

I am on Mac OS X 10.7, with Google App Engine 1.6.6 using Python 2.7.

Since PyCrypto [is supported on Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries#PyCrypto), I would expect it to work on the development server.

I am aware that `dev_appserver.py` prevents loading external files. However, I noted that `appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py` seems to have all the requisite files in the whitelist (e.g.`_fastmath`).

Note, in `app.yaml` I have

```
libraries: 
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
```

It seems as though I am missing something obvious but crucial. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT** For more details see: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12129

Comment: This thread seems related: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1627

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4612 is also related but not the same. It seems like the SDK is not very egg friendly and that it's very noticeable with pycrypto, but it's supposed to pick things up from site-packages.

Comment: Incidentally, I added `Crypto` (pycrypto's root python folder) to the root of my application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to install the **third-party library** yourself.
Google explains exactly which versions the provide on their platform,
so this should not be any problem.

Comment: Chris: I think you may be conflating "install" with "copy to the root of your project." The prior being necessary unless the library happens to be bundled with GAE dev kit - and pyCrypto is not, the latter being superfluous. The [Google docs state](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries) (for Django at least) "You do not need to add the versions you download to your application directory."

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get through this is create a virtual environment and install the pycrypto inside that. The reason your libraries inside `app.yaml` is not detected is most probably because you have multiple versions of python installed in your machine and the version you used to run the program might not be the same version where you installed the libraries